# Update State Array using Hooks (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

In my code, I have the following state array and hook:

```
const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
```

So in my code, I want to update the rows array by adding elements to it. The trouble I was having was writing it so that the new elements don't replace the old elements, but just adds to them. This is what I tried to do:

```
const filesUploaded = event.target.files;
const tempArray = rows
let timestamp = new Date();
let month = timestamp.getMonth();
let year = timestamp.getFullYear();
let date = timestamp.getDate();
let displayDate = month + "/" + date + "/" + year

for(var i = 0; i < filesUploaded.length; i++) {
    let newElement = {id: i + 1,
                      filename: filesUploaded[i].name,
                      size: filesUploaded[i].size / 1000000,
                     date: displayDate }
    tempArray.push(newElement)
}
setRows(...tempArray);
```

So the way it works is that the variable `filesUploaded` is an array that stores the files that the user has uploaded. I then created a variable `tempArray` that stores all the information from rows, and then you one by one add each of the elements from filesUploaded to tempArray. Then at the end, you set the "rows" state to equal the tempArray, since the tempArray will have all the information from the previous state as well as the new one.

The problem was every time I tried to do this, I encountered the following error:

```
TypeError: can't define array index property past the end of an array with non-writable length
```

This happens in the line "tempArray.push(newElement)" (third last line of code).

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this or another way I can update the rows state by adding elements to it, instead of overwriting it using hooks?

Answer (score 0):

dont' assign `tempArray = rows;`

do `tempArray = [...rows];`

`tempArray.push(something);`

`setRows(tempArray);`

state should not be mutated directly which were doing by

```
   tempArray = rows;
   tempArray.push(something)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays are copied by reference, if you need a copy, use the spread operator:

```
tempArray = [...rows];
```

But I wouldn't go with that. I would add newElement directly to rows:

```
setRows([...rows, newElement]);
```

(You have to define newElement in the global scope for that).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const temp = []
for(var i = 0; i < filesUploaded.length; i++) {
    let newElement = {id: i + 1,
                      filename: filesUploaded[i].name,
                      size: filesUploaded[i].size / 1000000,
                     date: displayDate }
    temp.push(newElement)
}

setRows([...rows,...temp])
```

Comment: just change setRows(...tempArray) with setRows([...tempArray]);

Comment: because your code means setRows(element1,element2,element3,......) not an array

Answer (score 0):

`rows` is readonly

```
const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
```

Here is assigned by reference, so it is readonly too.

```
const tempArray = rows //referenced and readonly too

for(var i = 0; i < filesUploaded.length; i++) {
    let newElement = {id: i + 1,
                      filename: filesUploaded[i].name,
                      size: filesUploaded[i].size / 1000000,
                     date: displayDate }
    tempArray.push(newElement) //can't use .push with readonly array
}
```

Instead, you should use spread operator

```
const tempArray = [...rows] //tempArray is a tottaly new array.
```

Now assign the new array to the state this way

```
setRows([...tempArray]);
```

Your code fixed

```
const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
const filesUploaded = event.target.files;
const tempArray = [...rows];
let timestamp = new Date();
let month = timestamp.getMonth();
let year = timestamp.getFullYear();
let date = timestamp.getDate();
let displayDate = month + "/" + date + "/" + year

for(var i = 0; i < filesUploaded.length; i++) {
    let newElement = {id: i + 1,
                      filename: filesUploaded[i].name,
                      size: filesUploaded[i].size / 1000000,
                     date: displayDate }
    tempArray.push(newElement)
}
setRows([...tempArray]);
```